# left join on same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to apply left join on same table but I am not getting the desired results.

I have this table

Table -- Pages

```
id    name        parent        status
1     AAA         0             draft
2     BBB         1             live
3     CCC         13            live
4     DDD         0             live
5     EEE         4             live
6     FFF         4             live
```

I want all the rows where id status is live and their parent id's status is also live.So in the above example id 2 should not appear as it's parent id 1 status is draft.

I have made a sqlfiddle -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6b31/4

Any help is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. It seems to be working. Note that a 'feature' of sqlfiddle is that it only lists duplicated column names once

Comment: It is including `id:2` in the results, when it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your fiddle's schema includes all cases. The cases you provided did not include a child *not live* without a parent.

This should do what you are expecting.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.parent, a.status
FROM pages a
LEFT JOIN pages b ON a.parent = b.id and b.status='live'
WHERE a.status='live' AND (b.status='live' OR a.parent=0)
```

Adjusted cases:

```
(1, 'AAA', '0', 'draft'),
(2, 'BBB', '1', 'live'),
(3, 'CCC', '13', 'live'),
(4, 'DDD', '0', 'live'),
(5, 'EEE', '4', 'live'),
(6, 'FFF', '4', 'draft'),
(7, 'GGG', '0', 'draft')
```

Comment: Thanks Tony.Quite close now.It's returning id:4,5,6 with the data which I have mentioned in fiddle but not id:3. id 3 should include.

Comment: Basically I don't want id 1,2,6,7 in your cases because either they are draft or their parent is a draft.

Comment: `ID:3` is omitted because the parent does not exist. In well designed data-architecture, this would be a sign of corruption or data-loss. Are you sure you want to include orphaned records?

Comment: Yes actually this is a sample data I created. That parent of id 3 is definitely there.100% sure.

Comment: Ahh it's not showing here because id:13 is not present.right?

Comment: correct, if you want to include orphans (parent record doesn't exist), adjust the where clause: `a.status='live' AND (b.status='live' OR a.parent=0 OR ISNULL(b.status))`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much for your help. I implemented it in my actual code and working great. Thanks once again.

Comment: note, that in a `left join` records that don't match will be joined with a value of `NULL`. This means that the second part of the where clause `AND (b.status='live' OR a.parent=0)` will result in false for joined records that don't exist, because neither 'live' nor '0' matches `NULL`.

Comment: Nice explanation.This is something like learning while working.